# se puede convertir el valor de una variable numerica que viene en un array, como valor numerico?

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo un valor numero que viene atra vez de un array,

```html
$valorusuario = $request->valorusuario;
```

El es un x o y numero, cuando lo veo con dd() aparece "1", es posible poder convertir esta variablea un valor numerico?

Es que me pasa algo curioso

```html
/**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function selectord(Request $request)
    {

        $valorusuario = $request->valorusuario;
        $int = (int)$valorusuario;

        $numero = 1;
       
     
        $consultarea=usuarios::where('user_id', $numero)->paginate(2);
        $usuariosOpciones=usuarios::pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')->unique();
        return view('usuario.consultareas',compact('consultarea','usuariosOpciones'));
      
    }
```

en este metodo si uso la variable $numero el pagido me sale perfecto, pero si uso la variable a la que le hice la conversion, carga la primera pagina pero no carga el resto, no entiendo por que el lio.

Answer (score 1):

me ha pasado alguna vez tener problemas para que el PHP tome la variable como no numérico.

En tu caso haría lo siguiente, usando las funciones del PHp que son para estos temas:

```
    if(!is_int($int)){
        $int = intval($int);
    }
```

Estos te castean las variables al tipo de dato que precisas.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, su opcion funciona perfecto, pero al parecer es un problema del metodo paginate(), ya que solo retiene el valor del filtro en la primera pagina, pero luego en las otras ya no lo retiene.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta es manejar un

```html
$usuarios->appends(['valoruno'=>$valoruno, 'valordos'=>$valordos]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para casos especiales en los que quieras realizar la conversión, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
$valorusuario = $request->valorusuario;
$int = (int)$valorusuario; //para un valor entero
$float = (float)$valorusuario; //para un valor float
```

De todas formas, en la mayoría de los casos no es necesario, ya que PHP hará la conversión automáticamente. Esto es parte de la [manipulación de datos](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.type-juggling.php) de PHP.

Comment: Gracias Mario, ya lo hice, pero me pasa algo raro, mira arriba lo que actualice

Comment: ¿Y si probás sólo con $valorusuario?

Comment: Ya lo hice, por esa razon ando mirando opciones pero ninguna me da

Comment: Cuando tienes dd($valorusuario) sólo te muestra "1", revisaste bien eso? me parece raro

Comment: asi es.. me muestra "1", por esa razon lo converti a int() de esa manera la variable queda en 1, pero aun asi... colocando esa variable en el paginado no funciona como deben, no se que diferencia habra entre esas dos variables, $numero he $int es como si algo los hiciera diferentes